# using async pipe in a feature module

Tags: angular

Hi I have a problem with my ionic app, that was not able to fix it; I want to use async pipe in one page (categoriesSelectorPage) inside my  feature module(CategoriesModule) this is my app.module.ts:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


import { ItemModule } from './modules/item/item.module'
import { DynamicFormModule } from './modules/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.module'
import {} from './modules/user/user.module'
import { FilterPopupPage } from './modules/item/pages/filter-popup/filter-popup.page';
import { SelectorItemsPage } from './modules/item/pages/selector-items/selector-items.page';
import { EditUserPage } from './modules/user/pages/edit-user/edit-user.page';
import { CategoriesModule } from './modules/categories/categories.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  FilterPopupPage,
  SelectorItemsPage,
  EditUserPage,
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    ItemModule,
    DynamicFormModule,
    CategoriesModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy},
   
    
    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

this is CategoriesModule.ts:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoriesSelectorComponent } from './components/categories-selector/categories-selector.component';
import { CategoriesViewerComponent } from './components/categories-viewer/categories-viewer.component';
import { ItemModule } from '../item/item.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [CategoriesSelectorComponent,CategoriesViewerComponent],
  imports: [
    
    CommonModule,
    ItemModule
  ],
  exports:[CategoriesSelectorComponent,CategoriesViewerComponent]
})
export class CategoriesModule { }
```

this is CategoriesSelectorPageModule.ts:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CategoriesSelectorPage } from './categories-selector.page';
import { ItemModule } from 'src/app/modules/item/item.module';
import { DynamicFormModule } from 'src/app/modules/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.module';
import { SorterItemsPipe } from 'src/app/modules/item/pipes/sorter-items.pipe';
import { FilterItemsPipe } from 'src/app/modules/item/pipes/filter-items.pipe';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CategoriesModule } from '../../categories.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CategoriesSelectorPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ItemModule,
    FormsModule,
    CategoriesModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DynamicFormModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  // declarations: [CategoriesSelectorPage]
})
export class CategoriesSelectorPageModule { }
```

I have seen that others  had the same issue, they fixed it importing CommonModule, but in my case, this did not work, so I would appreciate any help

Comment: What is the error you’re getting?

Comment: NG0302: The pipe 'async' could not be found!.

Comment: Can you add the component HTML, try to reproduce on stackblitz

Comment: You have `RouterModule.forChild([])`, but no `RouterModule.forRoot([])`. Any other errors in the console ?

Comment: no other errors, I changed RouterModule.forChild([]) with RouterModule.forRoot([]) nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, there were many mistakes in declared and imported modules, ionic build --prod helped me